Creating a specific route based on specific crossings and specific streets (in AnyLogic)
To model oversize load transport in AnyLogic, we have to force trucks (agents) to only use a set of specific roads and to change between those roads on specific crossings.
Is there a straight forward way or function to do this in AnyLogic or another software?

only manually, but that gives you full flexibility. One approach: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/agentify-your-network-pathfinding
